# Como fazer uma lista a partir de um request GET no Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Minha dúvida é como pegar o JSON do request e colocá-lo em um ArrayList para que eu possa inflar o RecyclerView. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona um `CoverterFactory` à instanciação do `Retrofit`, através do `addConverterFactory`, e no caso de o JSON devolver um Array, consegues mapear isso facilmente para uma ArrayList.

Comment: Valeu! Consegui efetuar corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter seu JSON em um JsonObject e ir capturando os atributos dele.

JSON

```
    {
     "nome": "José da Silva"
     "idade" : 30
     }
```

JAVA

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject("seu json aqui");
String nome = jsonObj.getString("nome");
int idade = jsonObj.getInt("idade");
```

Saida

```
Log.d("App", "Nome: " + nome);//José da Silva
Log.d("App", "Idade: " + idade);//30
```

Referência: https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-java-o-pacote-org-json/25480

Outra alternativa seria a biblioteca GSON, nela você converte diretamente um Objeto para Json e um Json para Objeto. Link:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html

Comment: Consegui resolver. Valeu pela ajuda!